# React.js show detailed info of a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I achieve to show  detailed page from a search function??

for example I have the data from the API call to be rendered in a list, but then I would like to hit the "more" link and show a detailed page of the selected list

example link: https://master.d1y6j5rvhgf8yj.amplifyapp.com/
with the initial data it works, but after I search it still direct to initial data

```
const findArticlesQuery = (query) => {
 axios.get(url)
  .then(res => {                
   [res.data].map((val) =>(        
     setArticleData(val.articles)        
   ))                                     
   }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error.response)
   });
 }

useEffect(
 () =>{
  findArticlesQuery();
  } ,[]
)
```

and then I have the article List but not sure how to create a detailed page,

```
<ArticleListItem articlesData={articleData}/>
```

```
const articleDataItem = articlesData.map((value, idx)=> (   
  <li key={idx} className="collection-item">
    <span>{value.title}</span>
    <a href={`/article/${idx}`}>More</a>     <--- I want to use this button to show detailed info            
  </li>
))
```

I can achieve this with router and matching params but only with the initial data, 
If I use the search function and the articlesData is updated, the link would still get the initial data and not the searched

I also must say that I have the useEffect on the App component which reset the data when I go to another page

Comment: You can create another api to fetch detail data for that `id`. You can call this api in `componentDidmount` or `getInitialState`.

Comment: In your `articleDataItem`, do you have any relation with map `idx` with your `articlesData`?

your `more` btn redirect user to `/article/${idx}`. I think there should some relation between these `idx` and data. Otherwise `/article/${idx}` this will be same each time no matetter data is same or not. And same is happening  in your case

Comment: @akshaypjoshi the problem is that, the data from the API, does not have a unique ID, but I get your point, maybe I can make another api call with the selected value!

Comment: maybe I should save the searched data in the localStorage and use it in the detail component to display , what do you guys think about this approach?

Answer (score 0):

In detail page, you shouldn't use index of list for show detail.

You should use a unique attribute of the data to display details.
example: data: [{code: 'abc', title: '...'}, {code: '', title: ''}...]

```
const articleDataItem = articlesData.map((value, idx)=> (   
  <li key={value.code} className="collection-item">
    <span>{value.title}</span>
    <a href={`/article/${value.code}`}>More</a>     <--- I want to use this button to show detailed info            
  </li>
))
```

In detail page, Search by received code value

Comment: the problem is that when I get into the detail page, the articleData is reset to the initial data, so my searched data is lost when I access the detail component

Comment: so initially it works perfect, when I search the list is updated perfect, but when I click on "more" after searching, the data is reset, so I get a detail page from the initial data, NOT the searched data :(

Comment: how is the structure between your components? Where do you put the component detail?

Comment: Hello @san, I have the App component with useEffect for the initial API call,  then I have to components the ArticleListItem and the Article components

<ArticleListItem articlesData={articleData}/> 
<Route path="/article/:id" render={() => <Article articlesData={articleData}/>} />

Comment: with the ID params in the URL I get the app to work great with the initial data, when it search its also doing good but when I click the more button, the data or state is reset to the initial call,

Comment: I think the problem is that when you redirected to detail page (/artircle/:id), the app component was re-rendered, so your data value was reset to initial data. So you should use state management (redux, ...) for this case